# Search on date field in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have my search field for name, email and created_at. I added search for name and emails field. For date field I have added the hint text "Date should be in MM-DD-YYYY format" and I want user to enter dates only in this format. If the date is entered in that format then I want to display all the records with that date. My searched result comes in string format e.g., "12-22-2015". I want all the dates whose created_at field is this to be displayed. For name and email my query is as: `@messages = Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? " ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)`. Need to modify the above query for created_at field also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
@messages = Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR messages.created_at like ? " ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", Date.parse("%#{@query}%", '%MM-%DD-%YYYY')).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Comment: ilike and like doesn't work with date field. It gives the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~* unknown

Comment: Still the error is coming: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~* unknown
LINE 1: ...es.to ilike '%06-01-2015%' OR messages.created_at ilike '201...

Answer (score 0):

Try following query to display same date records

```
@messages = Message.includes(:user).select('messages.*, users.name').where("users.name ilike ? OR messages.to ilike ? OR date(messages.created_at) = ? " ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", "#{@query.to_date}").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Comment: My @query is as: "10-07-2015" and its in MM-DD-YYYY format. I tried your query but I am getting blank result.

Comment: This Query syntax is working absolutely fine to me.Actually "10-07-2015" is a type of string and created at is type of datetime without conversion query will not work.